# Is it possible to put google extensions in a file form?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to convert a google extension into an executable file? I have a computer, that for unknown reasons will not let me use google extensions. tips on how to get google extensions working again would be appreciated.

SIDENOTE* (Hello, I'm new to the site, so If my question is not adequate, I would like to hear about it.)

Answer (score 0):

> I have a computer, that for unknown reasons will not let me use google extensions.

Perhaps elaborate on this a bit more. There might be a better solution rather than converting extensions to executables. Without more detail however, diagnosing the problem is nearly impossible.

As for your question about converting Chrome extensions to executables, it might be possible. I've heard about CRX Extrators that can unpack Chrome extensions which then can be manually loaded back into Chrome. Check out: https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-install-chrome-extensions-manually. Another possible solution that might enable you to not use third party software: [How to download Chrome extensions for installing in another computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/290280/how-to-download-chrome-extensions-for-installing-in-another-computer)

Before I'd try these different methods however, I would get to the root of why extensions are not able to be installed. Is there some sort of administrator restrictions on your computer? Perhaps reinstalling Google Chrome will fix the problem. Rebooting never hurts either.