# How to get raw files of extensions/add-ons in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: browser-addons, microsoft-edge

I am trying to install multiple extensions to my Microsoft Edge. However, since I am primarily using my university's Microsoft account, I can't install extensions directly since the administrators do not give users permit to install extensions to web softwares (the same goes for other engine e.g., Chrome). However, I can work around this by unpacking the extension files manually. However, I can't seem to find raw files for the extensions. Here are the extensions that I want to install:

[Adblock Plus](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bl/gmgoamodcdcjnbaobigkjelfplakmdhh)

[Mendeley Web Importer](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/mendeley-web-importer/mbcgpelmjnpfbdnkbebdlfjmeckpnhha)

[Microsoft Editor](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/microsoft-editor-spellin/hokifickgkhplphjiodbggjmoafhignh)

Going directly to the developer's websites also prompted the Edge Add-ons store, so it didn't work. Any insights? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by raw file(s)?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Files which I can manually load and unpack in the browser, so basically I'm thinking of downloading the extension file first, and then loading it in my browser

Comment: So you want to download the extensions without installing them?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio no I want to download the extension and install them manually, unlike the store which prompts us to install the extension automatically

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/1692028/855367

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio That answer doesn't work for Edge extensions, only Chrome extensions. When I [try it](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/buy/provision_freemium/gamjhjfeblghkihfjdpmbpajhlpmobbp?hl=en&gl=KR&pv=20210820&mce=atf,pii,rtr,rlb,gtc,hcn,svp,wtd,hap,nma,dpb,utb,hbh,ebo,hqb,ifm,c3d,ncr,hns,ctm,ac,hot,hsf,hfi,dtp,mac,bga,epb,fcf,rai,rma,lrc,spt,irt,scm,der,bgi,bem,ibg,dda,rae,shr,esl,hib,dsq,qso,pot,evt,eap,pet&_reqid=1836284&rt=j), I'm getting error `[[["er",null,null,null,null,400,null,null,null,3],["e",2,null,null,78]]]`.

Answer (score 0):

The URL to nab a CRX from the Microsoft store for Edge is exactly this:

```
https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?x=id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26installsource%3Dondemand&response=redirect
```

For example, [this link](https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?x=id%3Dodfafepnkmbhccpbejgmiehpchacaeak%26installsource%3Dondemand&response=redirect) will download the Edge CRX file for the latest release of uBlock Origin.

**Note** you will have to go into File Explorer or whatever and add the `.crx` extension yourself; the downloads are given extensionless GUID blob names.

---

h/t [`livre` on YCombinator](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=27306474)